# ExtJS: Change TreeLoader dataUrl

Tags: extjs, treeview

How to change `dataUrl` of a `TreeLoader`?

**Update:** sorry for causing confusion!

dataUrl can be set only in the constructor, there is no public property or method to change it later, after the instance was initialized. Hence, is it even possible to change it?

Comment: Looks to me like you can update `dataUrl` and then call `load`, probably passing the root node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each request (that's not "direct") appears to use the `dataUrl` directly. You should be able to just change it as a property, even though it's not reported as being public.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to change the URL of the Treeloader dynamically from the controller.

var mystore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('MyTreeStore');

```
        mystore.setProxy({
                             type: 'ajax',
                             url: 'app/searchid/'+searchText;
                         });
```

or

You can use the event beforeload to change the url.

```
mystore.on('beforeLoad',function(store, operation, eOpts){

        store.setProxy({
        type: 'ajax',
        url:"http://localhost/data/treegrid.json",
        actionMethods:{read:'GET'},
        timeout:9000000,
        noCache : false,
        reader: {
        type: 'json'
              }
        });
});
```